# Is it safe to alter a Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, resharper, windows-forms-designer

Resharper directs my attention to this line of code in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

...with "*Field can be made readonly*"

Is it safe to acquiesce, or should I just chalk it up to Resharper being a little too persnickety, and ignore it?

Resharper also flags Designer.cs for many other violations, such as:

*Redundant explicit delegate creation*

and, several times:

*Qualifier 'this.' is redundant*

### UPDATE

Here's how my settings look (I didn't alter them):

[image]

So...does this mean I need to manually add all those file extensions seen in Igal Tabachniks' scream shot? It seems it is set up for Windows 8 projects only; the quick-and-dirty util that "threw" these messages is a plain old Windows Forms app.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I added additional steps you could perform!

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to alter the `Designer.cs` file, but I would not advise it. The file is automatically generated and it will be generated again whenever you change the corresponding forms file. At top of the file it should mention this in a comment: `All changes will be lost`.

Comment: *Below* that line there is this:         /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
..and that appears to apply only to that one method, so...

Comment: I meant at the top of the file.

Comment: I know; I'm just saying the warning appears after the line that Resharper wants to alter, so perhaps changes to it would be retained and not regenerated/overwritten the next time the robot gerbils are awakened by the feeling of the compiler's lash on their metallic backs.

Comment: The whole file is replaced. Always. There is no way to keep changes inside these files.

Answer (score 4):

Those warnings from Resharper are ***guidelines*** not rules. They are only there to help with code readability and help prevent accidental coding errors by making your intent more obvious.

Now the Designer.cs file is generated by a machine and is intended to be read by a machine, not a person, so those guidelines are not relevant to the designer file.

I was 90% sure that the filters in Resharper excluded the Designer.cs from it's recommendation engine, but I would have to wait till Monday to check. You may be able to just add a filter to Resharpers settings to exclude `*.Designer.cs`

Answer (score 4):

You must have somehow modified your **Generated Code** setting in ReSharper, as ReSharper by default always ignores known generated files and regions, so it shouldn't flag any violations in any `.Designer.cs` files.

Make sure your settings look like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: it seems that most of your defaults are missing, for some reason. The best thing you could do is try to reset the settings to default.

The *fastest* would be to delete your `GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings`, located in `%appdata%\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny`, but this would obviously reset all your other settings (such as custom naming conventions).

Alternatively, you could manually edit the file (it's just an XML file), and remove all lines that start with:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/GeneratedCode/GeneratedFileMasks...
```

After deleting the entries, save the file (**make a backup first!**), and restart Visual Studio. Your defaults should hopefully be back.

Comment: I will add what I have, updating my original post.

Comment: ISTM there should be an easier way to just revert to factory settings; AFAICR I didn't change anything, anyway.